# objective c float numer conversion

Tags: objective-c, floating-point, numbers

```
  float f2,f1 = 123.125;
```

what is different between them?

```
  float f1 = 123.125,f2;
```

if I write code as

```
float f1,f2 = 123.125
```

the program will has different result

here is the full program

```
   float f2,f1 = 123.125;
    //float f1 = 123.125,f2;
    int i1,i2 = -150;

    i1 = f1; //floating to integer 
    NSLog(@"%f assigned to an int produces %i",f1,i1);

    f1 = i2; //integer to floating
    NSLog(@"%i assigned to a float produces %f",i2,f1);

    f1 = i2/100; //integer divided by integer
    NSLog(@"%i divied by 100 prouces %f",i2,f1);

    f2= i2/100.0; //integer divided by a float
    NSLog(@"%i divied by 100.0 produces %f",i2,f2);

    f2= (float)i2 /100; // type cast operator
    NSLog(@"(float))%i divided by 100 produces %f",i2,f2);
```

Comment: so what's the output from NSLogs..??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
  float f2,f1 = 123.125;  // here you leave f2 uninitialized and f1 is initialized

  float f1 = 123.125,f2;  // here you leave f2 uninitialized and f1 is initialized

  float f1,f2 = 123.125;  // here you leave f1 uninitialized and f2 is initialized
```

if you want to initialize both variables you need to do

```
  float f1 = 123.125f, f2 = 123.125f;
```

preferably you write like this (for readability)

```
  float f1 = 123.125f;
  float f2 = 123.125f;
```

note the "f" suffix, it indicates that it is a float value and not a double.

you can also do a define

```
#define INITVALUE 123.125f

float f1 = INITVALUE;
float f2 = INITVALUE;
```

Comment: The `f` suffix is optional in this context because the compiler will change the literal's type appropriately. :)

Comment: It is not the fact that the compiler converts the literal‘s type to the type of the declared object that makes it optional in this context. Rather, it is the fact that this literal is not changed by the conversion. Most double literals do change value when converted, and a few change to a value different from the same literal suffixed with an “f”.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to initialise two variables with the same value then use this syntax:

```
float f2 = f1 = 123.125f;
```

The code you are using is initialising one of the variables and not the other, hence the behaviour you are seeing.

Comment: hi,thanks for you answer, I try to change the code you just supplied, the whole program wont be works at all.